Azure web app not executing with principal identity
I'm running a web app that hosts a background service that connects to a service bus and processes messages. It also connects to a SQL Server database.
The problem occurs when the service tries to connect to the database because the container is not running with the Object (principal) ID. Instead, it runs with a ContainerUser and the database uses the Active Directory Managed Identity.
Do you have any idea why this happened?

Can you show the ARM/Bicep template you are using for the deployment and the code you are using to authenticate to Service Bus and to the database?
